# How can I use a HashSet<MyCustomClass> to remove duplicates of MyCustomClass?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a `HashSet<MyCustomClass> mySet = new HashSet<MyCustomClass>();` and I wish to remove all MyCustomClass's that contain the same values.

Let's say MyCustomClass looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
    Point point;

    public MyCustomClass(int x, int y)
    {
        point.X = x;
        point.Y = y;
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

I tried to implement `IEqualityComparer` like MSDN suggests, and pass it through the constructor of the `HashSet<MyCustomClass>();` but I ended up unsuccessfully.

What's the correct approach?

**EDIT:**

This is my `Chain` class and my `ChainEqualityComparer`:

```
public class Chain
{
    HashSet<Mark> chain;
    HashSet<Mark> marks;

    public Chain(HashSet<Mark> marks)
    {
        chain = new HashSet<Mark>();
        this.marks = marks;
    }       
    // Other methods...
}

public class ChainEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Chain>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Chain> Members

    public bool Equals(Chain x, Chain y)
    {
        if (x.ChainWithMarks.Count == y.ChainWithMarks.Count)
        {
            foreach (Mark mark in x.ChainWithMarks)
            {
                if (!y.ChainWithMarks.Contains(mark))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Chain obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode() ^ obj.GetType().GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And this is my `Mark` class:

```
  public class Mark
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Mark(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }
}

public class MarkEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Mark>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Mark> Members

    public bool Equals(Mark x, Mark y)
    {
        return (x.X == y.X) && (x.Y == y.Y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Mark obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode() ^ obj.GetType().GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

(I can pastebin the code if it's too much code...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the EqualityComparer or just override Equals and GetHashCode.

You must make sure that whatever you consider to be a *duplicate* is identified as having an equivalent hash code, and returning true when tested for equality.

My guess is that you weren't returning equal hash codes.  Could you post the code from your equality comparer?

As a test, you could do:

```
var set = new HashSet<MyCustomClass>();
var a = new MyCustomClass(1,2);
var b = new MyCustomClass(1,2);
set.Add(a);
set.Add(b);
Assert.IsTrue(a.Equals(b));
Assert.IsTrue(b.Equals(a));
Assert.AreEqual(a.GetHashCode(), b.GetHashCode());
Assert.AreEqual(1, set.Count);
```

A similar set of tests would be applicable to an equality comparer too.

**EDIT**

Yep, as suspected it's the hash code function.  You need to calculate it based on the values of the type itself.  A common enough mistake.

```
public int GetHashCode(Mark obj)
{
    return ((MyCustomClass)obj).point.GetHashCode();
}
```

That assumes `point` is the only state field in your type.

Comment: I think I'm having trouble with the implementation of the GetHashCode() method. Not sure if I just have to return a random number just as long as it's the same for objects with the same values?

Comment: I've updated my answer.   The hashcode must ALWAYS be the same for a given object.   If you want two objects to be hashed to the same bucket in the HashSet (ie. the second should replace the first, eliminating the duplicate) then you have to provide the same hashcode.  The hashcode value facilitates hashing in dictionaries and hashsets.  Think of it as a numeric address.  You should never have random numbers in a hash code function!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting tripped up becase two `Mark` instances with the same values won't be equal in your `ChainEqualityComparer` class. It doesn't appear like `MarkEqualityComparer` is ever used.

The line:

```
if (!y.ChainWithMarks.Contains(mark))
```

will always be false unless you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the `Mark` class. (Except if you have two references to the same mark in both Chain x and Chain y, which I'm presuming is not what you want).

If `y.ChainWithMarks` is a HashSet and you want to use `MarkEqualityComparer`, make sure you create that HashSet with the correct constructor including an instance of `MarkEqualityComparer`.

Since `Mark` is a value type, you might consider using a struct to represent it, since the .Net runtime then uses value equality instead of referential equality when comparing. I think this is actually the most correct implementation of your idea.

Comment: I changed the Mark to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point, which is a struct, I don't need any EqualityComparers for the HashSets that store the Points, correct?

Comment: Using a struct internally is different that actually being a struct. If Mark is still a reference type (using the class keyword), then it still won't compare. You could make Mark a struct by declaring `public struct Mark`.