# comparing two custom objects to prevent duplicates

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I have this Bookings object

```
Booking abc = new Booking { date = DateTime.Today, timeslot= timeslot[1], venue = venue};
waiter xyz = new waiter { id = 1, name = "xyz" };
xyz.bookedList = new List<Booking>();
xyz.bookedList.Add(bookingxyz);
```

I am looping through the above code. I want to avoid duplicate bookings based on date and timeslot
how can i do this?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: how rude....I already answered your question days ago, with a working example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097096/c-sharp-application-how-could-i-implement-dictionary-or-hashtable-for-this/18097582#18097582

Answer (score 5):

Is it duplicates in your **list** you are trying to avoid ? If yes then you shouldn't use a **list** as it allow duplicates.

A more sutable candidate would be [Hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), you will have to add an override to `GetHashCode()` in **Booking** and compute an hash based on **date** and **timeslot** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080322/how-can-i-use-a-hashsetmycustomclass-to-remove-duplicates-of-mycustomclass)

Then just before adding your **Booking** to the **HashSet** just verify that the object doesn't already exists using the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) method

Comment: yes its duplicates that's I am trying to avoid, unfortunately I've used list in my entire solution and will require lot more time converting from list to something else

Comment: Well the `HashSet` acts like a list, save for that no duplicate feature, so you will just have to change the type. Note that you could also use the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method of `List` in the same fashion, it just that it is better to use `HashSet` because you ensure that you will never have a duplicate because your model won't allow it.

Comment: using haslist or anything doesn't solve any overlap or time spans within existing start and end times. Also just checking with Contains only check the exact datetime. Not whether or not a new time has overlap, or is within known start and end times. Please check the solution given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097096/c-sharp-application-how-could-i-implement-dictionary-or-hashtable-for-this/18097582#18097582 That does check for overlap or whether or not a start and/or end time is within the range of known start and end times. Regards and enjoy

Comment: As far as I'm concerned that's an other question, I just gave the OP a solution to this one

Comment: you are right about that. Seems to OP is missing out on some relevant checking rules ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid adding duplicate values to your list, then you should not be using list first of all. 
Alternately you can add some kind of Id to you class and use as a key in a  dictionary 
                    OR
use [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) as suggested by Simon.

But if you want to find duplicates then you may use a linq query something like this:

```
bookedlist.Select( x=> new {x.date, x.timeslot}).Distinct();
```

Comment: -1 He wants to avoid duplicates based on date and timeslot. Venue was not included.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks. updated based on comment. you might want to update your -1 as well :)

Comment: I think he wants to include the venue column, but only from distinct rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change to a dictionary because it will not allow duplicate keys.  This will allow you to add booking objects to keys that don't throw a exception when added.

Comment: **Dictionary** do throw an exception when you try to add a duplicate or did you mean something else ?

Comment: @SimonRapilly it all depends on which way you attempt to add to it, [`Add(TKey,TValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) throws an exception, the [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) will just overwrite the current value with your new value.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ohhh right, keep forgetting about this one, well that's an other trail then, depending on what OP wants to do.